# remove the date from SERP magento2

Tags: magento2

Magento2 How to remove the date from SERP(Google Search Engine Results Page)?

My product details page is showing date in SERP, not sure from where I checked everything not sure from where it is coming

Comment: Must be somewhere in your product page's source. Since it's not there by default it's rather impossible to say without any more details. However, I guess you've got some shema.org markup added by some third party extension.

Comment: I checked many things but couldn't get the date. Can you guide something more how can I debug it? @ChristophFarnleitner